# How to transform this XML file into another using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML file:

```
<messages>
    <text>
        See you next <corr form="week">wk</corr>.
    </text>
    <text>
        Are you ready <number form="for">4</number> this <duplicate form="week">weeeek</duplicate> end<mark>?</mark>
    </text>
</messages>
```

that I want to change into this one by using XSLT 1.0:

```
<file>
<messages>
    <node>
        <text>See you next </text>
        <node>
            <text>week</text>
        </node>
    </node>
</messages>

<messages>
    <node>
        <text>Are you ready </text>
        <node>
            <text> for</text>
            <node>
                <text> this</text>
                <node>
                    <text> week</text>
                    <node>
                        <text> end</text>
                        <node>
                            <text> ?</text>
                        </node>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</messages>
</file>
```

In the second file, everytime we reach a tag with a "form" attribute, we have to create a new node with the form text in its own tag.

Here's my XSLT but it doesn't work well since the  tags aren't at the right place. Help please?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="file/messages">
        <xsl:for-each select="text">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- here, this doesn't work... -->
<xsl:template match="text"> 
    &lt;node&gt;&lt;text&gt; 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    &lt;/text&gt;&lt;/node&gt;
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@form]">
    <!-- gets the tag name -->
    <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="local-name()"/> 

    &lt;node&gt;&lt;text&gt;

    <!-- print the form text -->
    <xsl:if
        test="$attribute='corr' or $attribute='number' or $attribute='duplicate'">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@form"/> 
        &lt;/text&gt;&lt;/node&gt;
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- print the "?" -->
    <xsl:if
        test="($attribute!='corr' and $attribute!='number' and $attribute!='duplicate'">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        &lt;/text&gt;&lt;/node&gt;
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why the output is nested that particular way? This kind of nesting does not seem to serve any meaningful purpose to me. (i.e.: How is `"week"` a child of `"See you next "`? Semantically they are siblings, they ought to be children of the same parent, just like in the input.)

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its previous form - otherwise the answer would make no sense to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that's the output you want, try the following approach, known as "*sibling recursion*":

**XSLT 1.0**
***(edited to conform to the edited question)***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="messages">
    <file>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
    </file>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <message>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
    </message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/*[@form]">
    <node>
        <text><xsl:value-of select="@form"/></text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/text() | text/*[not(@form)]">
    <node>
        <text><xsl:value-of select="."/></text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following **test input**:

```
<messages>
    <text>See you next <corr form="week">wk</corr>.</text>
    <text>Are you ready <number form="for">4</number> this <duplicate form="week">weeeek</duplicate> end<mark>?</mark></text>
</messages>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
   <message>
      <node>
         <text>See you next </text>
         <node>
            <text>week</text>
            <node>
               <text>.</text>
            </node>
         </node>
      </node>
   </message>
   <message>
      <node>
         <text>Are you ready </text>
         <node>
            <text>for</text>
            <node>
               <text> this </text>
               <node>
                  <text>week</text>
                  <node>
                     <text> end</text>
                     <node>
                        <text>?</text>
                     </node>
                  </node>
               </node>
            </node>
         </node>
      </node>
   </message>
</file>
```

Comment: I corrected my second XML and the XSLT, sorry. Your answer is not quite the output I wanted

Comment: I added <node><text> </text></node> in the last 2 templates, but my </node> is still not closing in the right place..

Comment: @Nicolas Are you sure that is the result you want? That each successive node becomes the child of the one that precedes it? It doesn't seem to fir the logic of the input.

Comment: Yes I want to use that output as a tree structure.

Comment: @Nicolas An explanation *why* you want that output structure would have been interesting. (+1 for the solution)